# I want to write Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

but i dont know where to start! Which version of Ruby and Rails are the best?
And all documentations I can find are for Mac users. And im on Linux( ubuntu ).
I can allready write in C++
I hope you can help me!

Comment: if you are on windows try the windows installer - http://rubyinstaller.org/

Comment: by the way: you don't write a language, you write code. Or you write code using a certain language. Or you program.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To install Ruby language interpreter and the Rails framework itself you can visit http://railsinstaller.org website and download an installer for windows.

Speaking about applications development in Ruby on Rails, there is good tutorial written by Michael Hartl in link https://www.railstutorial.org/, that is highly recommended way to start development with Rails. This tutorial introduces to Ruby language and Rails framework and by following it you will build Twitter clone.

Comment: do you got a free variant?

Comment: ohh wait... it is free?

Comment: If you are talking about book, then it is already free to read online, just click on the link Read online free under the book cover image